# How can I create an NSMutableArray of structs?

Tags: objective-c

I created a structure like this

```
typedef struct Node {
    NSString* Description;
    NSString* AE;
    NSString* IP;
    NSString*  Port;
} Node;
```

I need to create `NSMutableArray` of this Node structure I need to know how create object of node path it to the `NSMutableArray` retrieve it and read for example the port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only store Objective-C objects in an `NSMutableArray`.

One route you can take is to use a standard C array:

```
unsigned int array_length = ...;
Node** nodes = malloc(sizeof(Node *) * array_length);
```

Another route is to wrap the structure in an Objective-C object:

```
@interface NodeWrapper : NSObject {
   @public

   Node *node;
}
- (id) initWithNode:(Node *) n;
@end

@implementation NodeWrapper

- (id) initWithNode:(Node *) n {
  self = [super init];
  if(self) {
     node = n;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  free(node);
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then, you'd add `NodeWrapper` objects to your `NSMutableArray`  like this:

```
Node *n = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
n->AE = @"blah";
NodeWrapper *nw = [[NodeWrapper alloc] initWithNode:n];
[myArray addObject:nw];
[nw release];
```

To retrieve the `Node` from the `NodeWrapper`, you'd simply do this:

```
Node *n = nw->node;
```

or

```
Node n = *(nw->node);
```

Comment: how to retrieve data from it or insert in it could u give me more details

Comment: Hi , I used objective c class, as u said , but while try to retrieve object nothing return  Node* object=(Node*) [NodesArray objectAtIndex:k];
 
 NSLog( object.Description );

Answer (score 45):

After running into this problem, I came across this thread which helped, but was more complicated than the solution I ended up with.

Basically the NSValue is the wrapper for your struct, you don't need to create a new class yourself.

```
// To add your struct value to a NSMutableArray    
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&structValue objCType:@encode(MyStruct)];
[array addObject:value];

// To retrieve the stored value
MyStruct structValue;
NSValue *value = [array objectAtIndex:0];
[value getValue:&structValue];
```

I hope this answer will save the next person a bit of time.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is my first time to use NSValue to encapsulate struct.

Comment: Very useful answer!  Question: how would this be affected with ARC turned on?  If the struct has NSString* fields, is ARC smart enough to hold on to the allocations until the struct entry is removed from the NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 13):

You can actually create a custom class (since it holds only `NSString` pointers) with struct values as instance variables. I think it'd even make more sense.

You can also create an array of `NSValue`s which hold these structures:

```
NSValue *structValue = [NSValue value:&myNode objCType:@encode(Node *)];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:structValue];
```

You can then retreive these structs as follows:

```
NSValue *structValue = [array objectAtIndex:0];
Node *myNode = (Node *)[structValue pointerValue];
// or
Node myNode = *(Node *)[structValue pointerValue];
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad you found this useful too .)