# Fetch Values from C-Struct in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, struct, nsmutablearray

This question has been asked a few times in SO, with the top two answers being:

[What's the best way to put a c-struct in an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516991/whats-the-best-way-to-put-a-c-struct-in-an-nsarray)

[How can I create an NSMutableArray of structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212815/how-can-i-create-an-nsmutablearray-of-structs)

The Apple Documentation also shows this process:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html

The consensus seems to be to turn the struct into an object by way of NSValue.  My problem when following this advice is that when I fetch back the data, I get bogus results.

My struct is very simple:

```
typedef struct { uint8_t r, g, b, a; } Pixel;
```

And as explained in the links above, I am able to add it to the array

```
NSMutableArray *ledColors;
```

By using NSValue in the following way:

```
    Pixel p_in = {0,0,0,1};
    NSLog(@"Pixel in: %d %d %d %d",p_in.r,p_in.g,p_in.b, p_in.a);

    NSValue *p_obj = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&p_in objCType:@encode(Pixel)];
//    NSValue *p_obj = [NSValue value:&p_in withObjCType:@encode(Pixel)]; //this seems to work too.


    for (int i=0; i<numLeds; i++) {
        [ledColors addObject:p_obj];
    }
```

However, when I retrieve/fetch the data as described in the linked posts above, I do not get the original {0,0,0,1} but random integers instead:

```
    Pixel p_out;
    [[ledColors objectAtIndex:0] getValue:&p_out];

    // Doesn't return the correct data
    NSLog(@"Pixel out: %d %d %d %d",p_out.r,p_out.g,p_out.b, p_out.a);
```

Comment: You need to debug the code. Use the debugger to view the values **at every step** through the code. Add NSLog() for values and find where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran the code below and it all worked correctly, which makes me think the problem is elsewhere.

```
Pixel p_in = {0,0,0,1};
NSLog(@"Pixel in: %d %d %d %d",p_in.r,p_in.g,p_in.b, p_in.a);
NSValue* v_in = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&p_in objCType:@encode(Pixel)];

NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];
[arr addObject:v_in];

Pixel p_out = {3,3,3,3};
[[arr objectAtIndex:0] getValue:&p_out];
NSLog(@"Pixel out: %d %d %d %d",p_out.r,p_out.g,p_out.b, p_out.a);
```

My guess is that `ledColors` is `nil` when you try to fetch the object back out, which will do nothing, and leave you with uninitialised memory inside of `p_out`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that was it.  This code ran inside my awakeFromNib and I hadn't added ledColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; beforehand.